# validate a text field with only 5 value

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <label class="user-reg-label fl">Percentage:<span class="required">*</span></label>
     <input class="user-reg-input fl" type="text" name="Percentage[]" id="Percentage1" value="" maxlength="5" />
```

> this is my html code.
>   i need to validate this input field with javascript to enter only 5 values like ***99.99***

Comment: If by "values" you mean "characters", that looks like 6 and not 5 to me.

Comment: It does validate for only 6 characters. So what is your question?

Comment: you already have maxlength right ?

Comment: what do you actually want to do?

Comment: i need like user enter s 2 number and after that if needed ". "must occur and then 2 numeric values and a "%"( may be by default)

Comment: Slightly off topic, but you should keep the "%" out of the input, just position the character next to the input in another tag. Reason being, you'll get undesired effects when formatting and place characters in front of the caret.

Comment: okk. then i  need code for only 5 inputs right??

Comment: Are you looking for some validation with regex?

Comment: yeah reg exp may b needed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is formatting, not validating, but it seems to be what the OP is really looking for ( I think ).

```
var input = document.getElementById("Percentage1"),
    onlyNumbers = input.value.replace(/\D/g,""), // Remove all nondigits
    cleanNumbers = onlyNumbers.substr( 0, 4 ); // Limit to four digits

// Add decimal if more than two digits in length
if( cleanNumbers.length > 2 )
{
    cleanNumbers = cleanNumbers.substr( 0, 2 ) + "." + cleanNumbers.substr( 2 );
}

input.value = cleanNumbers;
```

Comment: i need  user to enter only two numbers first and then dot should be outputed if he enter another number nad if needed after decimal two nos.

Comment: yeah may be like 99 and then if he enters any value it should turn  out to be decimal and then any number and alas %

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery something like the below works.

Textbox

```
 <input class="user-reg-input fl" type="text" name="Percentage[]" id="Percentage1" value=""  onpaste="return false"
        onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;" maxlength="6" />
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function ()
  {
     $('#Percentage1').keyup(function (event)
    {
        var currentValue = $(this).val();
        var length = currentValue.length;

        if (length == 2)
        {
            $(this).val(currentValue + ".");
        }
        else if (length == 5)
        {
            $(this).val(currentValue + "%");
        }
    });
});
```

This works for your basic requirements however there are a few things that need to be improved. If a user tries to delete multiple numbers it doesn't work or if they try to use the backspace key

Comment: I would say my input button constrains as well as @Dinesh Javascript code (I did the same answer but used Jquery) is probably the best answer in terms of automatic formatting for the user

Comment: i got this done. but have a pblm . if back space is pressed then pblm rises.. any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyup or keypress function for this

```
<input onkeyup="myFunction()" class="user-reg-input fl" type="text" name="Percentage[]" id="Percentage1" value="" maxlength="6" />

function myFunction()
{
var input = document.getElementById("Percentage1");

if( input.value.length > 6 )
{
alert( "too many characters" );
return false;
}
}
```

UPDATED:

```
<input type="text" id='text_field' onkeyup="check()"/>
    <script>
        function check()
        {
            var len=document.getElementById('text_field').value.length;
            if (len==2)
                document.getElementById('text_field').value=document.getElementById('text_field').value+".";
            if (len==5)
                document.getElementById('text_field').value=document.getElementById('text_field').value+"%";
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay then there is a text field where only if you put "99.99%" type pattern it will validate

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function fnc(){
pattern=/\d+[.]+\d+[%]/g;
text=document.getElementById("atext").value;
x=pattern.test(text);
alert(x);
}
</script>
<input type="text" maxlength="6" id="atext">
<input type="button" onClick="fnc()" value="click me">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

With Script portion

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val().match('(^100(\.0{1,2})?$)|(^([1-9]([0-9])?|0)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$)')) {
                alert("Percentage Matched");//Any thing which you want

            }
            else
                alert("Not Valid Input");
        });
    });
</script>
```

And Code for Textbox

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="test" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
```